# Keyboard is not getting hidden while my app is moving in background in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-input-method

Keyboard is not getting hidden while my app is moving in background in Marshmallow and some android OS. Here's my code

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(getWindow().getCurrentFocus()
                .getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(getCurrentFocus() != null) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```